# std::uncaught_exception does not work across DLL boundaries

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have a class in a DLL with a destructor that checks for std::uncaught_exception(). If uses in a try/catch-block from an executable it does not says true if an exception is thrown.

Here is some example code:
lib.h:

```
#pragma once

class __declspec(dllexport) C final
{
  public:
    ~C();
};
```

lib.cpp:

```
#include "lib.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

C::~C()
{
  std::cout << "C says: Uncaught: " << (std::uncaught_exception() ? "yes" : "no") << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "lib.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

class D final
{
  public:
    ~D()
    {
      std::cout << "D says: Uncaught: " << (std::uncaught_exception() ? "yes" : "no") << std::endl;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  try
  {
    C c;
    D d;
    throw 88;
  }
  catch (int a)
  {
    std::cout << "Code: " << a << std::endl;
  }
  {
    C c;
    D d;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And build everything using:

```
cl.exe lib.cpp /EHsc /LD /c /Fo:lib.obj
link.exe lib.obj /incremental:no /fixed:no /DLL
cl.exe main.cpp /EHsc /LD /c /Fo:main.obj
link.exe main.obj /incremental:no /fixed:no lib.lib
```

On Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2013 x64 and x86 I get the result:

```
D says: Uncaught: yes
C says: Uncaught: no
Code: 88
D says: Uncaught: no
C says: Uncaught: no
```

I would expect the second line to be

```
C says: Uncaught: yes
```

So the class in the DLL does not see that there is an exception caused stack unwinding causing it's destructor to be called. But the class directly located in the inner class sees it.

Are there any linker / compiler flags that make this work as expected?

Comment: BTW: Distinguishing betwen dllexport and dllimport when building and using the library does not change the result.

Comment: BTW2: Same for std::uncaught_exceptions(): Gives 0 where 1 is expected.

Comment: My guess would be that the dll's runtime has its own set of flags that return the uncaught_exception state. If you pass the function pointer of the app's std::uncaught_exception into the dll and call that function pointer instead, maybe you'll get the expected results.

Comment: The original code has run on VS2013 some one year ago without having this problem. At that time I was building with cmake. Now I reactivated that code for windows and build calling cl.exe and link.exe directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `/MD` the dynamic runtime compiler option.

Without one, the main executable and each DLL all have their very own copy of the runtime, with all its internal state replicated for each module.

Comment: Note that not sharing a runtime can cause many other problems, not just this one!